# CSS Relative Positioning Not working on Mobile View

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am New on Coding & I have an Issue on Positioning in Mobile.
I have added CSS and Div and setup myself it's working on PC View but on Mobile view its moved to the right side.not on exact pace.

DIV Class

hd vector background

199
               
                  
                   Loading...

CSS

```
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    left: 850px;
    bottom: 270px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

[PC VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXZAQ.jpg)

MOBILE VIEW

[MOBILE VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBiWv.jpg)

Your Help will be appreciated

Is It Possible to Merge Previous Table row with 2nd Single table..
without CSS 
1st Code 11 Image Post Code -

```
    <div class="panel-body">
<div class="col-md-12">               
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=11&orderby=date&order=DESC' ); ?>

  <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>       
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-hs-6">
                <?php
                    /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                ?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

2nd Single Image Table Code :

hd vector background

199 Loading...

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you are trying to accomplish? From your screenshots / code sample I can't tell what you are looking to do.

Comment: I used this CSS div.relative {
    position: relative;
    left: 850px;
    bottom: 270px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

Comment: I have used 3 rows with 4 coiumn in each row i want to replace 12th number column to new one  i made same size table code but dont know how its is merged without css please question again its updated

Answer (score 2):

In CSS, You should use percentage instead of pixels for value of left and bottom. It will render elements in better way. But in your case, I don't think that position is required.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of different screen size.The elements are positioned according to the screen size as you use positioning as relative,which means the element will adjust according to the size of screen. Try using other positioning methods, and if the problem still persist then use media queries to make your page responsive may that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you added "div" and By default, "div" tag is block-level elements begin on new lines try to add display: inline-block" to your css. or use media queries.

Comment: I don't have idea about  display: inline-block  can u add this your end   css is here :      div.relative {
    position: relative;
    left: 850px;
    bottom: 270px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}

Answer (score 0):

You might, as @Amhil Med said, use a media query. This means you can link to a different stylesheet for mobile views, and fix the issue without stuffing up your normal view on computers